# AJAX / History - When is the right time to call the `pushState` method in AJAX app?

Tags: ajax, readystate, pushstate

I'm working with AJAX and history object (with the `.pushState` method). I just want to know when is the right time to call `pushState` method? Is it before request? after request? or on what state of XMLHttpRequest's `readyState` should I call it? As much as possible, I want it to behave like a normal request (without AJAX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only HTTP 200's normally get added to a browsers history. So it probably makes sense to do

```
readyState == 4 && status == 200
```

That way if your Ajax call has a 404 error for some reason it won't be added to history just like in normal browsing.